# Ungroup buttons (shapes) using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following VBA to insert two `buttons` into my Excel sheet and group them together:

```
    Sub Insert_Buttons()

    Sheet1.Select
    Dim Button_01 As Button
    Set Button_01 = Sheet1.Buttons.Add(423.75, 0, 48, 15)
    Dim Range_Button_01 As Range
    Set Range_Button_01 = Sheet1.Range("B6:D7")
    Button_01.Name = "Button_01"
    With Button_01
    .Top = 30
    .Left = 76
    .Width = 50
    .Height = 20
    .Text = "Button_01"
    End With

    Sheet1.Select
    Dim Button_02 As Button
    Set Button_02 = Sheet1.Buttons.Add(423.75, 0, 48, 15)
    Dim Range_Button_02 As Range
    Set Range_Button_02 = Sheet1.Range("B6:D7")
    Button_02.Name = "Button_02"
    With Button_02
    .Top = 5
    .Left = 76
    .Width = 50
    .Height = 10
    .Text = "Button_02"

    Sheet1.Shapes.Range(Array("Button_01", "Button_02")).Group

    End Sub
```

All this works perfectly.

---

However, now I want to use another VBA to **ungroup** the `buttons` which I inserted with the above VBA. Therefore, I tried to go with the following:

```
Sub Ungroup_Buttons()
Sheet1.Shapes.Range(Array("Button_01", "Button_02")).Ungroup
End Sub
```

However, with this VBA I get `runtime error 1004`. 
What do I need to change in my code so I can ungroup the buttons?

Comment: Have You tried using ThisWorkbook and name of the Sheet1 like: ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1name").Shapes.Range(Array("Button_01", "Button_02")).Ungroup ?

Comment: I think so since I use this in the VBA Button_01.Name = "Button_01"

Comment: @Michi The you can give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58025350/11167163) a try I bet that it can do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe give this a try :

```
Sub Ungroup_Buttons()

Set ButtonList = Sheet1.Shapes.Range(Array("Button_01", "Button_02")).Group

ButtonList.Name= "ListToUnGroup"

Sheet1.Shapes.Range("ListToUnGroup").Ungroup


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answert but I get runtime error 438 on line ButtonList.List = "ListToUnGroup"

Comment: @Michi did a mistake its `.name` and not .List sorry, I edited my answer

Comment: @Michi Glad I could help you !